# Install pandas when calling the PythonRunner object

Tags: python, pandas, scala, apache-spark

I have a python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

print('Hello World')
```

I'm trying to run it in my Scala project using a PythonRunner object:

```
import org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Paths

object PythonRunnerApp extends App{

  val pyFilePath = this.getClass.getResource("").getPath + "/hello.py"

  PythonRunner.main(Array(pyFilePath, "hello.py"))

}
```

As a result, I get an import error: `ImportError: No module named pandas`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a19562665/IdeaProjects/PythonRunner/target/scala-2.12/classes//hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkUserAppException: User application exited with 1
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner$.main(PythonRunner.scala:103)
    at PythonRunnerApp$.runUsingSpark(PythonRunnerApp.scala:15)
    at PythonRunnerApp$.delayedEndpoint$PythonRunnerApp$1(PythonRunnerApp.scala:27)
    at PythonRunnerApp$delayedInit$body.apply(PythonRunnerApp.scala:8)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:80)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:80)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:78)
    at PythonRunnerApp$.main(PythonRunnerApp.scala:8)
    at PythonRunnerApp.main(PythonRunnerApp.scala)
```

Is there any way I can ask PythonRunner to install pandas?

UPD:

Here is another example of running python scripts:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#import pandas as pd
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   print('Hello, ' + line)

# this is hello.py
```

And Scala application:

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile(getClass.getResource("hello.py").getPath, true)
val test = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List("Body!")).repartition(1)

val piped = test.pipe(SparkFiles.get("./hello.py"))

val c = piped.collect()
c.foreach(println)
```

**Output:** Hello, Body!

But the question remains open to me. Can I, as a cluster user, install pandas on workers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install all necessary Python dependencies across every executor before submitting Spark applications into your cluster

Keep in mind that you're not using Pandas here, and SparkSQL should *probably* be used instead

Comment: Still, I need to find a way to deliver python dependencies to workers.

Comment: Read the Spark documentation about `--py-files` argument, or like I said, you can SSH to every machine and run pip commands. Ansible would make that easier